# Draw samples from complicated distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling, sample

Let $X_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ be IID 0/1 indicators with $E[X_i] = p$.

Let $E \subseteq \binom{[n]}{2}$ be a set of pairs $\{i,j\}$ with $|E| = m$. Consider the following random variable:

$$
Y = \sum_{\{i,j\}\in E} X_i X_j
$$

I would like to draw $m$ IID samples from $Y$. The obvious way to do it
is for each sample $X_i$ to flip a coin and then compute the sum. This runs in time $O(n)$ to sample the n $0/1$ indicators and $O(m)$ to compute the sum. Therefore, for $m$ samples it will take $O(m^2)$ time. Is it possible to do provably better than that in terms of computation time?

Comment: Are you assuming the $X_i$ are independent or not?

Comment: $X_i$ are independent.

Comment: OK.  The answer will depend on the relationships between $n$, $m$, and $p$.  I believe you can achieve a $O(\max(p,1-p)^2n^2)$ expected-time solution, but that is worthwhile only when $pn\ll m$ or $(1-p)n\ll m$.